# SQL Like operator whitespaces backwards search

Tags: c#, sql

I have Person table in database. which has `firstname`, `lastname`, `age`, `country`.

person1: `John,Tom,29,italy`

I want to search by country last letter `%y` but because country field is defined 15 characters so the rest of the field is white spaces. like that: `italy----------` where `-` means white space.

so it never finds Italy because the field ends with white space.
how can that be fixed? to remove white spaces before running the `Like` operator!

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies, it worked like that:
where trim(country) like '%y'

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution would be to use `RTRIM(Country)`

A better solution would be to update this column:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Country = RTRIM(LTRIM(Country))
```

and remove extra spaces in code where a new country is added or updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are storing the country as a `char()` field rather than a `varchar()` field.  I would suggest changing the definition to `varchar(255)` or something like that -- 15 characters seems too short for country names.

If you cannot do that, you can also do:

```
where country like replace(cast(country as varchar(255)), ' ', '') like '%y'
```

There are other ways to express this, but that should work in most databases (you don't mention the particular engine you are using).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`Select * from table where right(country,1)='y`'

[See here for Right()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx)